# How to programmatically trigger refresh primeNG datatable when a button is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a refresh button that is outside the primeNG datatable.
How do I programmatically trigger to refresh the datatable?

something like this:

```
<div class="pull-right">
  <button
    id="FilterBtnId"
    (click)="???">
  </button>
                </div>
<p-dataTable
   #datatable
   [value]="datasource"
   [(selection)]="jobs"
   [totalRecords]="totalRecords"
   selectionMode="multiple"
   resizableColumns="true"
   [pageLinks]="10"
   [rows]="10"
   [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100]"
   [paginator]="true"
   [responsive]="true"
   [lazy]="true"
   (onLazyLoad)="getNewDatasource($event)"
   (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
   >
     <p-column [style]="{'width':'40px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
     <p-column *ngFor="let col of dt.colDefs" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.headerName" [sortable]="true">
     </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 28):

The [Angular form guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#add-a-hero-and-reset-the-form) contains a small trick that could be used as a *workaround*, it consists on recreating the dom by adding `*ngIf` to the element to control its visibility

```
visible: boolean = true;
updateVisibility(): void {
  this.visible = false;
  setTimeout(() => this.visible = true, 0);
}

<button (click)="updateVisibility()">
<p-dataTable *ngIf="visible">
```

Comment: awesome and simple!

Comment: At first I didn't dare to use this solution because it seemend to simple for me it was just unbelievable at the all it was the simplest and the best solution ever lol 
I am just wondering why primeface doesnt provide a method that do the trick though =/

Comment: Thanks I used this and it worked, but I am getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. – P. Huhn yesterday

Comment: this is a better solution since making another call to the API is unnecessary. Big up.

Comment: using this trick inside popup caused fast hiding/showing experience that was unpleasant to me.

Comment: this works, but unfortunately causes "flicker", the table disappears and reappears at the correct size, probably an OK trade-off, but be aware of it.

Answer (score 6):

We can have small trick to update the dataTable here:
we can recreating the div by adding *ngIf to the element to control its visibility by this it will update dataTable also.

```
    visible: boolean = true;
    updateVisibility(): void {
      this.visible = false;
    }
    <button (click)="updateVisibility()">

    <div *ngIf="visible">
        <p-dataTable></p-dataTable>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

If the table is in Lazy mode (loads data dynamically from a server with pagination and so on...) a better way to do this (preserving the page number, sorting, filter and so on) is listed [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=44788).

**The solution is:**

On your component template:

```html
<p-table [value]="yourData" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadUserData($event)" ...
```

On your component code:

```js
private lastTableLazyLoadEvent: LazyLoadEvent;

loadUserData(event: LazyLoadEvent): void {
    this.lastTableLazyLoadEvent = event;
    // Lots of beautifull data loading code here 
    // (like calling a server trough a service and so on)...
}

...
```

And when you want to reload the table (e.g. when you insert or delete an item from the server):

```js
this.loadUserData(this.lastTableLazyLoadEvent);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know since when it is available but you can call the method `createLazyLoadMetadata` to create the object you need for the server with sort, filter etc. So you can simply write

```
@ViewChild('dt') dataTable: Table;
if (this.dataTable) {
   this.loadData(this.dataTable.createLazyLoadMetadata());
}

loadUserData(event: LazyLoadEvent): void {
    this.lastTableLazyLoadEvent = event;
    // Lots of beautifull data loading code here 
    // (like calling a server trough a service and so on)...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a variable that can remove the primeng datatable and reassign it.

```
visible: boolean = true;
updateVisibility(): void {
  this.visible = false;
}
<button (click)="updateVisibility()">

<div *ngIf="visible">
    <p-dataTable></p-dataTable>
</div>
```

This is a easy solution.What it does is just remove the dom of the element and reassign it

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the list in the component, the table refresh automatically.
Example after confirm a delete operation:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Interface } from '../..//model/interface.model'
import { InterfaceService } from '../../service/interface.service'
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { ConfirmDialogModule, ConfirmationService } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './interfaces.component.html'
})
export class InterfacesComponent {

    interfaces: Interface[];

    constructor(
        private interfaceService: InterfaceService,
        private confirmationService: ConfirmationService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.find();
    }

    find() {
        this.interfaceService.query().then(interfaces => this.interfaces = interfaces);
    }

    confirm(id: number) {
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            message: 'Are you sure that you want to delete this record?',
            accept: () => {
                this.interfaceService.delete(id).then((_interface) => {
                    this.find();
                });            
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pls Try its working for me**

```
refreshTable(){this.loadCustomers(this.lastEvent);}

loadCustomers(event: LazyLoadEvent) { this.lastEvent = event; this.loading = true;  this.service.getAll(event).subscribe( data => { this.loading = false; this.tableData = data['results']; }, error => { this.loading = false; } ); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Rendere2 can be helpful

```
@ViewChild('table') table: Table;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
}

refreshTable(){
    const dataTableRef = this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.table.el.nativeElement, true);
    dataTableRef.focus();
}
```

dataTableRef.focus() will refresh the grid